# how to insert array of object in redis using nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis

here is the array of object,want to store in redis by mapping and grouping on categoryId

```
var cars = [
{
    'category': 1,
    'model': 'r8',
    'year': '2012'
}, {
    'category': 1,
    'model': 'rs5',
    'year': '2013'
}, {
    'category': 2,
    'model': 'mustang',
    'year': '2012'
}, {
    'category': 2,
    'model': 'fusion',
    'year': '2015'
}, {
    'category': 3,
    'model': 'optima',
    'year': '2012'
} ];
```

and i want to store in redis(hmset)
suppose the key name is item,

```
1: [
    {   'categoryId':1
        'model': 'r8',
        'year': '2012'
    }, { 'categoryId':1
        'model': 'rs5',
        'year': '2013'
    },
 ],
2: [
    {   'categoryId':2
        'model': 'mustang',
        'year': '2012'
    }, { 'categoryId':2
        'model': 'fusion',
        'year': '2015'
    }
],

3: [
    {   'categoryId':3
        'model': 'optima',
        'year': '2012'
    }
]
```

and so that i can fetch records on the basis of category id using hmget(item,2)

Answer (score 0):

for using Redis in node.js I install and require `redis-async` from npm

I grouped input data with `groupingCars()` function.

for insert data in to redis I user `insertCars` function.

for fetch data from Redis I user `fetchCar` function.

```
var client = redis.createClient({
  host: "127.0.0.1", // hostname
  db: 0, //redis db
});
let groupedCars = [];
var cars = [
  {
    category: 1,
    model: "r8",
    year: "2012",
  },
  {
    category: 1,
    model: "rs5",
    year: "2013",
  },
  {
    category: 2,
    model: "mustang",
    year: "2012",
  },
  {
    category: 2,
    model: "fusion",
    year: "2015",
  },
  {
    category: 3,
    model: "optima",
    year: "2012",
  },
];
// grouping Cars based on Category
async function groupingCars() {
  cars.forEach((car) => {
    if (!groupedCars[car.category]) {
      groupedCars[car.category] = [];
    }
    groupedCars[car.category].push(car);
  });
}

//inserted each item into redis
async function insertCars() {
  groupedCars.forEach(async (gpCar, category) => {
    await client.hmset("item", category, JSON.stringify(gpCar));
  });
}

//fetch data from redis based on category
async function fetchData() {
  let result = await client.hmget("item", "1");
  result = JSON.parse(result)
  console.log(result);
}


groupingCars()
insertCars()
fetchCar();
```

Data Stored in Redis
[image]